# Is there an equation $f(k,m,n)=n$ where $n$ is the number of applications of the Ackermann function needed?

Tags: recursion, tetration, hyperoperation, ackermann-function

Using the definition of the Ackermann function on [page 247 of this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Knoebelchv.pdf), (sidenote, great paper):
$$
 \alpha(k,m,n) =
\begin{cases}
m+n,  & k=1 \\
m, & n=1 \\
\alpha(k-1,m,\alpha(k,m,n-1)),& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Is there some function $f$ such that $f(k,m,n)$ returns the number of times $\alpha$ is used to calculate $\alpha(k,m,n)$?

Some trivial values would be $f(1,m,n)=f(k,m,1)=1$, and $f(2,2,2)=2$, found manually by counting the number of $\alpha$s in the expanded form of $\alpha$.

Note: There is neither a tag for "ackermann-function" or "recursion", I lack the privilege to create these but I feel they would have some limited use.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense in the vocabulary of mathematics. Does there exist a function? Sure. You have just defined such a function. 

You mean is there a nice neat closed form? How many times does a recursive algorithm call upon itself might be a good CS question. I think your question might get more play on cs.stackexchange.com but I am not so sure of the community there and how they would respond.

Comment: @Mason I initially intended to ask this on stackoverflow, but I felt it wasn't CS-related enough

Comment: Oh no. Ackermann Function is right out of the CS Camp. They should be very interested: Check out: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47227/time-complexity-of-ackermanns-function. The problem will be that you are going to have a more precise question to make much progress.

Comment: @Mason is there a simple way to migrate questions?

Comment: Look it up on the Meta and post the link here. I dunno know.  but I need to.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your comment. You are correct: StackOverflow is not the right choice. Maybe cs.se after you shop your question.

Comment: Not sure what you meant about [tag:ackermann-function] and [tag:recursion] since they already exist. I have [edit]ed your question to include these tags.

Comment: How are you getting $f(2,2,2)=2$? I'm getting $3$, since $\alpha(2,2,2)=\alpha(1,2,\alpha(2,2,1))=4$ with $3$ instances of $\alpha$.

Comment: Also, would $$f(k,m,n)=\begin{cases}1,&k=1\text{ or }n=1\\1+f(k,m,n-1)+f(k-1,m,\alpha(k,m,n-1)),&\rm else\end{cases}$$ work as an answer?

Comment: Note that $m$ does not change over the iterations, so much of the same analysis applies.